# CSS HTML "color: gold;" not working on mobile

Tags: html, css, ios, mobile

Im building a website and I cant get this text color to change.

[image]

(link to full size image of text im trying to change)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/e5FQ1.png

Ive tried using

```
color: gold;
```

and ive also tried using the `!important` tag as well.

Ive spend hours just sitting and staring but no ideas have come to me.

The link to the webiste is https://luxtent.by/ and when you are inspecting element make sure to set the view type to iPhone 6/7/8.

Also another issue that I cant figure out is that the icons are white on screen but, when if you look in inspect element, they are gold. [image]

If you have any ideas feel free to try them out in inspect element and let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Could you please add screenshots with styles in dev console for the element you need to be gold

Comment: I don't have acsess to dev, its my friend's site and she asked me for help with this problem. All I have is inspect element. I might be able to get screenshots of the styles later today when she wakes up.

Comment: If `gold` is not working then use `color: #ffd700;`

Comment: Still no luck with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your color change is not working because you are using the grayscale filter on the parent element

```
.w-iconbox {
    filter: grayscale(1) contrast(5) !important;
    transition: 0.1s;
}
```

Remove this code and you'll be able to set any color